# How to stop Quarto from deleting gfm files when rendering to html?

Tags: r, quarto

I need to render a `.qmd` file simultaneously to both gfm (`.md`) and `.html`, but quarto deletes the existing `.md` when I render the `.html` file. Is there any way to keep both formats?

The Quarto website seems to suggest that it's possible: https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/authoring/rstudio.html#rendering, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

This is my file:

**format_test.qmd**

````
---
title: "format_test"
format:
  html: default
  gfm: default
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code
into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto 
see <https://quarto.org>.

## Running Code

When you click the **Render** button a document will 
be generated that includes both content and the output 
of embedded code. You can embed code like this:

```{r}
1 + 1
````

What I've tried so far:

**1. Clicking Render in RStudio:**

- Produces a `.html` file with a `gfm` tab. However, clicking on the `gfm` tab results in a blank page with the phrase "Not found". [Screenshot of HTML render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YafTw.png)

My working directory has a `format_test.html` file, but not the `format_test.md` file:

```
list.files()
```

```
[1] "format_test_files" "format_test.html"  "format_test.qmd"  
[4] "format_test.Rproj"
```

**2. Rendering via the terminal: Same result as above.**

```
quarto render format_test.qmd --to gfm,html
```

```
processing file: format_test.qmd
                                                                                                            
output file: format_test.knit.md

pandoc 
  to: html
  output-file: format_test.html
  standalone: true
  section-divs: true
  html-math-method: mathjax
  wrap: none
  default-image-extension: png
  
metadata
  document-css: false
  link-citations: true
  date-format: long
  lang: en
  title: format_test
  


processing file: format_test.qmd
                                                                                                            
output file: format_test.knit.md

pandoc 
  to: >-
    commonmark+autolink_bare_uris+emoji+footnotes+gfm_auto_identifiers+pipe_tables+strikeout+task_lists+tex_math_dollars
  output-file: format_test.md
  standalone: true
  default-image-extension: png
  toc: true
  number-sections: true
  
metadata
  title: format_test
```

```
list.files()
```

```
[1] "format_test_files" "format_test.html"  "format_test.qmd"  
[4] "format_test.Rproj"
```

**3. Rendering them individually: Quarto deletes the `.md` file and replaces it with `.html`**

This command gives me a `format_test.md` file:

```
quarto render format_test.qmd --to gfm
```

```
processing file: format_test.qmd

output file: format_test.knit.md

pandoc
to: \>-
commonmark+autolink_bare_uris+emoji+footnotes+gfm_auto_identifiers+pipe_tables+strikeout+task_lists+tex_math_dollars
output-file: format_test.md
standalone: true
default-image-extension: png
toc: true
number-sections: true

metadata
title: format_test

Output created: format_test.md
```

```
ls

format_test.Rproj       format_test.md          format_test.qmd
```

Running this command deletes `format_test.md`, and replaces it with`format_test.html`.

```
quarto render format_test.qmd --to html
```

```
processing file: format_test.qmd

output file: format_test.knit.md

pandoc
to: html
output-file: format_test.html
standalone: true
section-divs: true
html-math-method: mathjax
wrap: none
default-image-extension: png

metadata
document-css: false
link-citations: true
date-format: long
lang: en
title: format_test

Output created: format_test.html
```

```
ls
format_test.Rproj       format_test.qmd
format_test.html        format_test_files
```

**sessionInfo:**

```
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.1

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
\[1\] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
\[1\] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
\[1\] compiler_4.2.2  tools_4.2.2     rstudioapi_0.14 knitr_1.42  
\[5\] xfun_0.37
```

**Quarto version:**

```
[✓] Checking versions of quarto binary dependencies...
      Pandoc version 3.1.1: OK
      Dart Sass version 1.55.0: OK
[✓] Checking versions of quarto dependencies......OK
[✓] Checking Quarto installation......OK
      Version: 1.3.340
      Path: /Applications/quarto/bin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the underlying markdown file when rendering to `html`, simply use the option `keep-md: true`,

```
---
title: "format_test"
format: html
keep-md: true
---
```

---

Now there's a reason why you are not getting the markdown file after the command `quarto render format_test.qmd --to gfm,html` ends executing. Quarto actually generates the `format_test.md` file at first, then it continues to the rendering to html. After it produces the html output, it then removes the markdown file.

Therefore, try the following command instead specifying the `html` at first and then `gfm`,

```
quarto render format_test.qmd --to html,gfm
```

---

But if you do not want to care about the format order, use the `keep-md: true` specifically for `html` format as follows,

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format:
  html: 
    keep-md: true
  gfm: default
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code
into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto 
see <https://quarto.org>.
```

Then running either of the commands below generates both of the html and markdown files,

```
quarto render format_test.qmd --to html,gfm
```

or

```
quarto render format_test.qmd --to gfm,html
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the top of the file to look like this:

```
---
title: "format_test"
format:
  html: default
  gfm: default
  execute:
    keep-md: true
---
```

This is covered in the [execution options](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/execution-options.html) documentation.

Comment: It seems that the solution from @neilfws doesn't work. However, when I updated it to have the execute YAML field at the same level as format, I succeeded in rendering the qmd file.